# Recursively Deleting a Directory

Tags: java, file, recursion, traversal, delete-file

I have this section of code:

```
public static void delete(File f) throws IOException 
    {
        if (f.isDirectory()) 
        {
            for (File c : f.listFiles())
            {
                delete(c);
            }
        }
        else if (!f.delete())
        {
             throw new FileNotFoundException("Failed to delete file: " + f);
        }
    }   



 public static void traverseDelete(File directory) throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException
    {
        //Get all files in directory
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : files)
        {
            if (file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("word"))
            {
                boolean containsMedia = false;

                File[] filesInWordFolder = file.listFiles();

                for ( File file2 : filesInWordFolder ) 
                {
                    if ( file2.getName().contains("media"))
                    {
                        containsMedia = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (containsMedia == false)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        delete(file.getParentFile());
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (file.isDirectory())
            {
                traverseDelete(file);
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry for the lack of commenting, but it's pretty self-explanatory, I think. Essentially what the code is supposed to do is traverses a set of files in a given directory, if it encounters a directory named "word", then it should list out the contents of word, and then if a directory called "media" does NOT exist, recursively delete everything within the parent directory of "word" down.

My main concern comes from this conditional:

```
if(!filesInWordFolder.toString().contains("media"))
```

Is that the correct way to say if the files in that array does not contain an instance of "image", go ahead and delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work.

```
File[] filesInWordFolder = file.listFiles();

if(!filesInWordFolder.toString().contains("media"))
```

will give you a string representation of a File array -- which will typically have a reference.

You have to iterate through the files to find out if there's any in there that contain the word media.

```
boolean containsMedia = false;

for ( File file : filesInWordFolder ) {

if ( file.getName().contains("media") ){
 containsMedia = true;
break;
}

// now check your boolean
if ( !containsMedia ) {
```

Comment: I edited my original post and included my new traverseDelete method following your example, but it is still not deleting the folders correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems to me like your requirement is, if your directory passed into this method `traverseDelete(directory)` contains a "word" subdir which does not contain a "media" file , you want to delete `directory` itself .. is that correct?

Comment: Not exactly, you have everything correct until the "delete directory" part, I want to delete the parent directory of word, which is a sub directory of "directory".

Edit: Also, media is a directory itself (but I don't think that's important)

Comment: @This One.Pr0grammer -- parent directory of word is "directory". You directory.listFiles() and one of those files is "word" .. at least thats what your program looks like.

Comment: Parent Directory of word is "Folder X", "directory" is the parent of "Folder X". The program is meant to traverse any directory it encounters until it meets a directory named "word" in which case it recursively deletes the parent directory "Folder X" and all it's contents. From the code, it looks like it SHOULD do that. I am not sure why it is not. :/

Comment: ok. Short of me rewriting the code, I'm not sure I can help. I would suggest running in debug mode or putting SYSOs to figure out whats going on. Your program seems logically correct to me.

Comment: yeah same here. Thank you for your help though, I still appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Well using `toString()` will give you a String representation of the file (in this case the files). The String representation should contain the file name. If your set purpose is to check for any instance of a file containing the word "media" in the directory, you are fine.

In the example you are printing the String representation of the File array. Instead you should iterate through the File array and check the String representation of each individual File as so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < file_array.length; i++) {
  if ((File)file_array[i]).toString().equals("your_search_term")) {
    // The file contains your search term
  } else {
    // Doesn't contain the search term.
  }
}
```

Comment: Just did a print statement of `System.out.println(filesInWordFolder.toString());` and it's simply returning memory locations :/.

i.e. `[Ljava.io.File;@1cd8669
[Ljava.io.File;@337838
[Ljava.io.File;@119cca4`

Comment: @This One Programmer I appologize, I misread something in your code. I will update the answer to reflect this.